# HttpWebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] failed with error

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

When I'm trying to set Referer header I'm getting the following error:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "http://somesite.com/";
```

> This header must be modified with the appropriate property"

But there is no "appropriate" property for Referer.

What could be the reason?

up: I'm using PCL which is referenced by MonoTouch/MonoDroid/WP7.5 projects (Client Profile 104)

Answer (score 2):

```
request.Referer = "somesite.com";
```

Comment: monodroid project references pcl where httpwebrequest is created.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx):

> The Headers collection contains the protocol headers associated with the request. The following table lists the HTTP headers that are not stored in the Headers collection but are either set by the system or set by properties or methods.
>
> - Referer – Set by the [Referer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) property.
>
> The Add method throws an ArgumentException if you try to set one of these protected headers.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx):

> **HttpWebRequest.Referer Property**
>
> Gets or sets the value of the *Referer* HTTP header.

Monodroid documentation: [System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Referer Property](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P:System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Referer)

You can set the property as follows:

```
request.Referer = "http://somesite.com/";
```

Comment: monodroid project references pcl where httpwebrequest is created.